# apple-app-site-association JSON not showing up?

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-app-site-associate, apple-app-site-association

I have implemented my association [like it is done here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39965525/15502014), but when I then go to check the JSON by doing: `https://day21.co/apple-app-site-association`.

​
This shows up:

```
{"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[]}}
```

Rather than what I have in the file:
​

```
    {
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": [
        {
            "appID": "BID.com.Name.SignUpFlowclub"
            "paths": ["*"]
        }
        ]
    }
}
```

​

Here you can see the placement of the file, which I firebase deployed to hosting successfully. https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX5K2.png
​

**What am I doing wrong?**

​

Answer (score 0):

you trying to read `.txt` file.

just change that extension to `.json` and read again.

And read json like below.

```
func readJson() {
        let jsonUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "apple-app-site-association", withExtension: "json")!
        do {
            let data = try Data(contentsOf: jsonUrl, options: .mappedIfSafe)
            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableLeaves)
            let result = jsonResult as! [String : Any]
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
```

Comment: well when your using Apple-app-site-association it appears your not supposed to use ANY EXTENSION... json or txt... I'm assuming the computer automatically marks it as txt by default but is not actually txt as it has no extension (the file)

Comment: okay. can show me your code where you generate `apple-app-site-association` so i might help you.

Comment: yes, i believe it is in my question... i generated the apple-app-site-association by doing $ touch apple-app-site-association in the teriamnal